# How to return the table of sqlite3 by column in web.py

Tags: python, sqlite, web.py

I am practising web.py. In web server, I have a sqlite3 database, and I would like to return its records by a http visit. How can I add newline break between each record in browerse?

Here is what I get in browser, and I want to add linebreak between each rocord, like:

```
[('2017-02-23 10:19:13', 1.68, 1.01),     
('2017-02-23 10:19:51', 1.03, 1.9),     
('2017-02-23 10:21:41', 1.97, 1.6),     
('2017-02-23 10:22:39', 1.57, 1.75),
```

My code as below:

```
import web
import sqlite3

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)


class index:
    def GET(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('customer-01.db')
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT *  from datasource")
        return cursor.fetchall()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, could you provide us with a [mcve]? That way we can see what you've tried and advise you on the best course of action. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your `return cursor.fetchall()` returns text, which in a browser is displayed without any special formatting -- that's why it's one long line.

To have it look better in a browser, return HTML instead. Then you can add `<br/>` between each line (or, format it as a table or, or...)

You could use web.py templates, but since you're trying to keep it simple, all you need to do is explicitly set the Content-Type and add some HTML.

Update your GET:

```
def GET(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('customer-01.db')
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * from datasource")
    web.header('Content-Type', 'text/html')    # you're sending HTML rather than text
    ret = [str(x) for x in cursor.fetchall()]  # Convert each row to string
    return '<br/>'.join(ret)                   # return single string, with <br/> between rows
```